# R am/pm datetime issue

Tags: r, datetime

I haven't found an answer that works for me yet.  I have data that has observations on a 5 minute basis.  I have start and end time columns named (creatively) `STARTTIME` and `ENDTIME`. I read.csv the data into R.  When I do the `STARTTIME` and `ENDTIME` are treated as factors.  The "cells" in the data frame are populated with date time values such as "7/2/2016 11:25:00 PM".  So, I tried the following:

```
df$STARTTIME <- as.POSIXct(as.character(df$STARTTIME), format = "%m%d%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz ="EST")
```

When I run that code the whole column is replaced with NA.  Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: your format specification is wrong, include `/` in date part. use: `as.POSIXct("7/2/2016 11:25:00 PM", format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz ="EST")`

Comment: OMG, One Million Thank you!!!!!!!!